# Read other xml elements based on the root node and one of the element?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, xmlnode

My XML is given below.

```
<UrlRoutes>
  <ActivityPR>
     <Source>activity/editactivity</Source>
     <DestinationController>Activity</DestinationController>
     <DestinationAction>Editactivity</DestinationAction>  
  </ActivityPR>
  <UserSettings>
     <Source>settings/subscriptions</Source>
     <DestinationController>UserSettings</DestinationController>
     <DestinationAction>GetUserPreferenceSettings</DestinationAction>
  </UserSettings>
</UrlRoutes>
```

I will have `Source` element value in a var say `sourceX` . Ex

```
SourceX = "settings/subscriptions"
```

or

```
SourceX = "activity/editactivity"
```

I am trying to get the parent node using the below code, let me know if there is something wrong

```
XmlElement xmlNode = xmlDoc.GetElementById(SourceX);
XmlNode parent = xmlNode.ParentNode;
```

Now for the combination for the parent node(say `ActivityPR` or `Usersettings`) and `Source`, I have to find the corresponding `DestinationController` and `DestinationAction`.

How do I do that? Prefer traditional XML as opposed to LINQ as rest of the code is in that form.

```
if(node!=null)
        {
            XmlElement routeElement = (XmlElement)node;


            strController = routeElement.GetElementsByTagName("DestinationController")[0].InnerText.ToString();
            strAction = routeElement.GetElementsByTagName("DestinationAction")[0].InnerText.ToString();


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already loaded the XML into your `XmlDocument` - correct?

In that case, you should be able to use something like this:

```
string xpath = string.Format("/UrlRoutes/*[Source='{0}']", sourceX);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

if(node != null)
{
    // use the node to do whatever you need to do
}
```

The xpath expression basically selects any node under `/UrlRoutes` that contains a `<Source>` element with the given string as its value. This means: the values of `<Source>` need to be unique.

**Update:** if you **know** you want to search only inside nodes `<UserSettings>`, you can make your XPath expression more selective:

```
string parentNode = "UserSettings";
string sourceX = "settings/subscriptions";

string xpath = string.Format("/UrlRoutes/{0}[Source='{1}']", parentNode, sourceX);
```

But with this more selective XPath, you would **not** be able to find a node when you have `sourceX = "activity/editactivity"` in your example (since that is **not** inside a `<UserSettings>` node)

**Update #2:** I would probably use this code to grab the elements inside your node:

```
if(node != null)
{
   string dc = node.SelectSingleNode("DestinationController").InnerXml;
   string da = node.SelectSingleNode("DestinationAction").InnerXml;
}
```

That way, you don't need to convert to an `XmlElement` first.

Comment: Thanks Marc, the xml seems to be in such a way where say there may be more than one UserSettings node in the xml, but the combination of UserSettings and source will be unique, that is y I thought I need to search on the combination of these 2 items(parent node and SOurceX), I dont know whether ur code works there, will it?

Comment: @AdarshK: as long as the value of `source` is unique in your entire XML document - then my code works just fine.

Comment: Oh rite, the Source seems to be Unique, hence your original code will work I believe, Right?

Comment: @AdarshK: yes, if the `<Source>` is unique - then you can go with my first XPath expression

Comment: I added a code at the end of my question, can you confirm if it will work?